# How can I send Gravity Forms as a PDF via email?

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I am building WordPress website and I want my clients to fill out the form then it sends all the forms in a pdf as an attachment to the email. How can I do it?

I really appreciated if SO can tell me how to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using PHP Composer or know how to use Composer? What level of PHP do you know to add this functionality? This can be done using a PDF PHP package to generate the PDF and send it via the GF notification.

Comment: The easiest solution if you already have Gravity Forms, and you are not familiar with coding, is to use a free plugin like [Gravity PDF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-pdf-extended/#description) or a paid one.
If you expect more help in the future, please understand that we expect programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the add-on! It can customize pdf template
https://add-ons.org/plugin/gravity-form-pdf-generator-attachment/